# How can a customer get access to an older app release?

Tags: ios, itunes-store

I've got a report from a customer saying the latest update to our app isn't working on his iPad 1. Since I don't have an iPad 1 to test on I don't have any way of fixing this, but he says the previous version worked fine. He spoke to Apple and they say he needs a "special code" from us to download the older app.

Does anyone know what this special code or voucher is and how I go about sending him one?

Comment: As long as the developer keeps updating the same bundle identifier the store will keep track of the versions.

Comment: Yes, but not sure how this is helpful.

Comment: No one can help you.  The developer would have to do the right thing.  This is site to answer programming questions.

Comment: I am the developer! Since I can't fix the problem I'm asking how I can release the old app to this customer.

Comment: The only way to release an app to someone is to add that customer device to your development account. By the way, did you change your bundle identifier in the latest version of your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on the Apple Developer Forums as well:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/965324#965324

> You can't "delete" the current version.  You would have to submit a new version and then go into the previous version list and disable the former version.
>
> Okay, but would this enable iOS5 users to downgrade to the previous release that worked for them?
>
> No. The user would have to delete the app from their device then download the latest compatible version to their devices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this special code exists. I suppose what he means is allowing downloads of older app versions.

So let's say you wanted to download an app that requires iOS 7, but an older version only required iOS 6, which is what you have. The App Store will let you know that the latest version is not compatible, but will then download the older version that was still compatible with the older iOS. The latest version that is still compatible will be downloaded.

[image]

Comment: Right now our app is marked as working with iOS 5 so I assume this isn't going to work - if I release a new app marked as not supporting iOS5 the user will get this message and end up with the existing app which doesn't work.

Do I need to delete the current version and re-release it as not working with iOS5?